# Por que "excessivamente" tem "x"?

Tags: ortografia

Por que a palavra "excessivamente" tem um "x", sendo que o "x" não muda nada na pronúncia?

Comment: Excessivamente vem de excessivo, que vem de excesso, que vem do latim excessu (o X tem som de KI)

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, se quiseres adicionar seu comentário como resposta, eu aceito-o como respondido.

Answer (score 3):

> sendo que o "x" não muda nada na pronúncia?

Para mim muda. 
Consultando o [forvo](https://forvo.com/word/excesso/), noto que a pronúncia pt-PT é consideravelmente diferente da pt-BR ("eis-ce-so" vs "es-ce-so").

Portanto:

- No contexto português é necessário e afeta bastante a pronúncia.
- No contexto brasileiro é uma questão histórica: da mesma maneira que escrevemos o h em "há" e "helicóptero" e "hospital".

Há-de vir um acordo ortográfico mudar isso. :)

---

Em português europeu, leio excesso como "eis-ce-so".

E sem x, ecesso, ficaria ê-ce-so ou quando muito e-ce-so/i-ce-so.
Perderia o som "-ch" que o x imprime ao *ex*, ficando "eis".

Comment: Eu acho que a resposta é um bocado mais complicada. O radical é erudito do latim e provavelmente a palavra estremar veio importada juntamente do latim com uma declinação que altera a consoante. (Há um termo técnico para isto mas agora perdi a referência.) Pensei em tentar responder a pergunta verificando a pista do latim mas não tenho conhecimentos para isso.

Comment: Deus me livre de mais um acordo ortográfico.

Comment: Haver e hospital vem do latim, e o H tem som de R na pronúncia latina (talvez não na pronúncia à portuguesa, mas no exemplo do forvo de um francês, sim) dessas palavras. Mas em português, creio que o H é mudo, no forvo tem a pronúncia portuguesa e brasileira e ele é mudo em ambas. Então, creio que a letra está lá mais pela sua origem latina mesmo.